# Two element margin collapsed vertically then actual size?

Tags: jquery, html

I am learning CSS3 from W3Schools. This note is confusing me, please help me to understand this example.

The `h1` element has a bottom margin of `50px` and the `h2` element has a top margin of `20px`. Then the vertical margin between `h1` and `h2` should have been `70px` (50px + 20px). However, due to margin collapse, the actual margin ends up being `50px`. Why is this?

```css
h1 {
  margin: 0 0 50px 0;
}

h2 {
  margin: 20px 0 0 0;
}
```

```html
<h1>Heading 1</h1>
<h2>Heading 2</h2>
```

Comment: It's because opposing margins overlap each other. You can see this effect occurring if you inspect the DOM using your browser's developer tools. I'd also suggest not using W3Schools as their articles are often outdated and sometimes just plain wrong. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) is a far better resource.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing

Comment: There's gotta be dozens of dupes for this question

Comment: thanks i got a perfect tutorial

Answer (score 1):

The margins are collapsing on each other, resulting in a 50px gap. If you wish for a 70px margin, at least one of them must be specified to 70px.

Comment: Come on, this is even not very good answer for upvotes. Plus is not accurate even. *"If you wish for a 70px margin, at least one of them must be specified to 70px."* is wrong for example.

Comment: The OP upvoted it. You  are not the OP. please try to understand that it helped the OP, clear or not. @dfsq